# SMTP MTA to MTA authentication

Tags: smtp, authentication

I still have trouble understanding how a receiving MTA authenticates the forwarding MTA.

I imagine an email that is forwarded by domain A's MTA<sub>A</sub> to domain B's MTA<sub>B</sub>.

Steps to take by MTA<sub>A</sub>:

1. Find MX record of domain B in DNS.
2. Connect, (verify X.509 to ensure authenticity) and forward message.

But now, what does MTA<sub>B</sub> do? As it does not want to be spammed and has most probably enabled user authentication, I see 2 options here:

1. MTA<sub>B</sub> also immediately checks the MX record of MTA<sub>A</sub>, to ensure it is talking to a registred mail server.
2. MTA<sub>B</sub> only relies on black,-, whitelisting

From my local host I get "poor reputation" issues when trying to connect.

I could not find any information on this in the RFC or question with my key words besides [this entry](https://serverfault.com/questions/392770/smtp-session-between-2-mail-servers-on-the-internet-without-authentication?rq=1). Yet, the latter only answers **how** to find and connect to a MTA but not what mechanisms are used for authentication.

I would be grateful for any hints :)

Comment: keywords to google: SPF, DMARC, DKIM

Comment: Thank you for your hint.
Though, these mechanisms only work **after** I received an **email/envelope**.
So this means MTA accepts the mail and then performs DNS related checks on it? But doesn't this result in high work load if I accept emails, check them and then discard them afterwards?
Also, some SMTPs just refuse/close connection immediatley, and no SPF, DMARC and DKIM is happening, so I think there must be something going on in advance.

Comment: "Reputation" is tied to IP address. Many SMTP servers will tell you to go away if you connect from a residential Internet connection, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, the classical checks are:

- as soon as the IP address of an incoming connection is known: make a reverse DNS lookup of the IP address - if it fails, it probably isn't a well-configured legitimate MTA.
- once the reverse lookup completes: do a forward DNS lookup on the name returned by the reverse lookup - if the resulting IP does not match the connecting IP, it probably isn't a well-configured legitimate MTA.
- as the connecting party sends the initial `HELO`/`EHLO` message: does the claimed FQDN in HELO/EHLO match the actual FQDN reported by the DNS lookups? If not, the connection can be treated with some suspicion, although it might not be terminated outright. If the connection claims an "insider" domain name but comes from an "outsider" IP address, authentication requirement should be enforced: it might be an attempt to fool old/badly configured mail servers, or just a mobile email client.
- as the connecting party sends the `MAIL FROM:` line: is the claimed source FQDN within the domain(s) this mail server is responsible for? If so, this is probably outgoing mail. In today's networks, the connecting party should at this point have already enabled encryption (STARTTLS) and authenticated successfully - if not, the connection can be terminated right here. (Non-authentication-capable clients in trusted internal networks might be explicitly whitelisted to skip the crypto+authentication requirement.)
- If the claimed `MAIL FROM:` address is not within the domain(s) this mail server is responsible for, this should be incoming mail - is the `RCPT TO:` address within the domains this mail server is supposed to handle mail for? If not, this is a relay abuse attempt -> terminate connection.

After these checks, the connection is probably legitimate enough that `DATA` can be accepted and the more involved SPF/DKIM/DMARC and blacklist checks started. There is no universal SMTP authentication between different organizations' MTAs.

There is also an option of greylisting: if this is the first connection from a previously unknown source address, the mailing attempt can be rejected outright with a "temporary failure" error code. A legitimate server will wait a while and then make a new attempt. If a specified minimum amount of time has passed from the first attempt, the receiving MTA will now process the incoming email as normal and if the email passes all the other checks, further connections from the same source will be accepted without the initial delaying.